# Javascript - Trigger function return from another function

Tags: javascript, function, return, conditional-statements

Is it possible to trigger a function "return" from another function without the explicit keyword?

Example:

```
let a = function(){

    //Option 1 - Duplicated on function aa
    if(!bb()){
        return false;
    }

    //Option 2 - No check needed as it's delegated on function b
    b(this);
    . . .
}

let aa = function(){

    //Option 1 - Duplicated on function a
    if(!bb()){
        return false;
    }

    //Option 2 - No check needed as it's delegated on function b
    b(this);
    . . .
}

let b = function(fnc){
    if(check)
        fnc.return("hi");
}

let bb = function(){
    if(check)
        return false;
}

a(); //Returns "hi" if condition on function b meets
```

The problem that I want to solve is avoiding to duplicate the check on each function and avoiding to set the returning value (bool) on the parent function which can be different as it's explicitly defined each time.

What I'm asking is if there's any way to achieve this the way the "pseudo-code" does, with a higher abstraction level.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `return b()` inside `a` and `if(true) return "hi";` inside `b`

Comment: Well, you can throw an exception that the calling function does not catch, but otherwise no.

Comment: @Akshay if I use `return` keyword inside a, it will always end execution on that point

Comment: Then try `const bValue = b(); /* .. rest */ return bValue;`

Comment: @ProtectedVoid: You can *conditionally* `return` from `a` based on the result from calling `b`.  It's not really clear what actual problem you're trying to solve or what led you to think you need to do this.

Comment: @David The problem I want to solve is the delegation of the conditional check to B so I don't have to duplicate the check on every function.

Comment: @ProtectedVoid: Then what you have is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), because the code shown has no duplicated logic or anything resembling the underlying problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @David Duplicated logic added